# C: _access_s() can't find the folder

Tags: c, filesystems

This is a structure of a location where is the application executed:
[image]

The purpose of an application is to check if there is the folder named `Folder`. This is a function that is responsible for this:

```
bool Initialize(const char * c_pszFolder)
{
    if (_access_s(c_pszFolder, 00) != 0)
    {
        printf("Error! Folder doesn't exist.");
        return false;
    }

    printf("Success! Folder does exist.");
    return true;
}
```

Here is how the function is called:

```
int main()
{
    Initialize("Folder");
}
```

According to a documentation the second argument of `_access_s()` is the number of a case you want to test. In my case I would use: `00 Existence only.`. Although, when I run the application the app return false, which is really confusing due to results of debugging:
[image]

After trying to get more information by using `_get_errno()` I've got errno value 2, which stands for: `ENOENT  No such file or directory`. But the folder exists.

Comment: I think you need to give to _access_s() the path to your folder. In you case it would be `./Folder` instead of `Folder` because `./` is the current directory.

Comment: When trying to call by `Initialize("./Folder");` the app is still returning `false`.

Comment: With which program do you debug your application ? Maybe it doesn't use the same environment in Debug therefore not having access to the Folder. Did you try to run it using powershell at the location of the folder  ?

Comment: I've been debugging it via `Local Windows Debugger` which is integrated in Vistual Studio. When I executed an application in standard way it works as intented, thanks. Is there any option I'm used to check to set correct behaviour of the debugger?

Comment: Probably the current directory is not what you think it is. Check by calling the [`GetCurrentDirectory`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winbase/nf-winbase-getcurrentdirectory) function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just change your current directory like this

`Project | Properties | Select Configuration | Configuration Properties | Debugging | Working directory`